# Check if array in object item contains substring

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know I can iterate through an array and check if one of it's items EQUALS a item, like this:

```
var myObject = {
    myArray : ["someString", "anotherString"]
}

for (var obj in myObject){

    if (myObject[obj].indexOf("someString") > -1) {
    //In the array!
    } else {
    //Not in the array
    }

}
```

But how do I check if any of the arrays items CONTAINS the item passed into the indexOf-method.

What I mean is: If this part looks like this: `if (myObject[obj].indexOf("some") > -1)`. I still want it to catch the `"someString"` in `myArray` and make the if-statement return true

Comment: You need to iterate over the strings in the arrays and perform separate indexOf checks.

Comment: If you don't care about `some`'s position within `myArray`, you could test for its presence by casting the array as a string.  Examples:  `myObject[obj].join('').indexOf("some") > -1`  or  `myObject[obj].toString().indexOf("some") > -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already looping through the object to get each array. Now you need to loop through the array to check if the string exists in each element. The snippet below will let you check each entry in `myObject` to see if the value is in each array.

```js
var myObject = {
  myArray: ["someString", "anotherString"],
  anotherArray: ["fooString", "anotherString"]
}

for (var obj in myObject) {
  var exists = false;
  var theArray = myObject[obj];
  for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
    if (theArray[i].indexOf("some") > -1) {
      exists = true;
    }
  }
  
  if(exists) {
    alert(obj + ' yes');
  } else {
    alert(obj + ' no');
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's say the string passed into the indexOf-method looks like this: `indexOf("some else")` . How do I still get myArray to be true ?

Comment: I need it to be true even if I pass in another string, as long as it contains "some". Which could be any of these for example: "a someString b", "a some b", "some a b" ect.